# ASP.NET Website inside Webforms application?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web

We've inherited an ASP.NET website. We've already converted it to a web application for different reasons.

But there are 2 folders with 2 .aspx pages inside that do some really kludgy things (creates a new aspx file with its corresponding code behind and save it inside one of those folders).

So when the project was a simple website, that worked because the created pages on runtime were compiled at request. This is not applicable to a web application.

We don't have time to re-code those ugly pages and do it as it should. So, is there a way to have those 2 pages (and the generated-at-runtime ones) excluded from the project and inside a website that is compiled at request? What other alternatives could you think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiple Web Applications on a single site by designating them as separate applications within separate Virtual Directories in IIS.  For this, just create a new Virtual Directory in IIS, right-click and go to Properties.  Under the "Virtual Directory" tab, click Create.  This will designate that Virtual Directory as a separate application.

The end result will be that "mysite.dom/VirtualDirectory1" and "mysite.dom/VirtualDirectory2" will be separate applications that can even run under a different ASP.NET runtime.

**EDIT TO ADD** that the downside of this is that the two applications are completely separate and cannot share Session or Application information.  This can be easily solved via a Database or some other data store.

Comment: Yes, I knew something about that. Anyway I'll have to check because the site is running in a shared-hosting environment, so I'm not really sure right now if I can do anything I want with IIS and stuff... I'll check later. Thanks for the fast reply =)

Comment: I know on GoDaddy shared hosting, I can make subdirectories "Application Roots" which is exactly the same as what I described above.  I would think most hosts would not give you a hard time about doing this because it doesn't require any major configuration or setup.  Good Luck!