# Asp.Net Nested Websites

Tags: asp.net

What I'm trying to do is have a portfolio type of site where there is the main site and then say a customers folder and in each customers folder is the customers site.  so something like mysite.com/cuustomers/customer1 would bring up there whole site.  What do I need to do to the web config file of the nested site to get this to work.  To test this, I created two new projects, compiled them, and uploaded them.  The home page works but when I navigate to the home page of the nested site I get:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Can someome point me in the right direction please.  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate -- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556867/asp-net-website-inside-webforms-application/3557121#3557121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really is more of a server configuration issue, suitable for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). However, quick fix. In IIS, make the sub-applications `virtual directories` or `applications`.